# how to add api data in datatable , flutter

Tags: api, flutter, datatable

I want to populate datatable with api data. here is my code where i am getting record from api, and creating a datatable.

```
  _getRecord() async{
    Dio dio=new Dio();
    var data={
      'username': getname,
      'month': getdate,
      
    };
    await dio
    .post(localhostUrlAttendanceHistory,data: json.encode(data))
      .then((onResponse)async {
       
        print(onResponse.headers);
        print(onResponse.statusCode);
        print(onResponse.data);
        print(onResponse.data['data'][0]['username']);
      }).catchError((onerror){
        print(onerror.toString());
        
    });

    

  Widget attendanceHistory()=>
  DataTable(columns: <DataColumn>[
    
    DataColumn(label: Text("Date"),numeric: true),
    DataColumn(label: Text("Time in"),numeric: true),
    DataColumn(label: Text("Time out"),numeric: true)
  ],
  rows: [
    DataRow(cells: <DataCell>[
      
      DataCell(Text("data")),
       DataCell(Text("data")),
        DataCell(Text("data"))
    ])
  ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body:Stack(children: <Widget>[
         Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 270, 10, 0),
      child: attendanceHistory(),)
    ])
```

My **api data** looks like

data: [{ username: ABC, Date: 2021-06-14, TimeIn:  2:26:07 PM, TimeOut: 4:04;05 PM}]}

please help if anyone know how to do it.